# how to plot a linear function with TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I am plotting a simple linear function. The plot looks fine, but I want to extend the function up to x=7. Anyone knows, please how to do that?

My code is the following:

```
\usepackage{tikz} %for drawings
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tkz-fct} %for functions


\begin{figure}%[H]
\centering                                             
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[width=400pt,axis x line=center, axis y line=center, ylabel={$n$},xlabel={$x$},xmin=-2,xmax=8,ymin=-2,ymax=8]
        \addplot+[mark=yes] (\x,{5-0.8*\x});
        \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Effect of the parameter $n$ on the particle nodes scaling}
\label{fn1}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Set `domain=-1:7` (or whatever domain you want to evaluate your function over).

Comment: Thank you jake, bu I do not want to modify the domain. I just want to modify the extension of my function. I will ask it clearly.

Comment: Got it, thank you very much. I did not find the other question before. Should I delete this question?

Comment: No need to delete the question, we can close it as a duplicate. That will make it easier for others with a similar questions to find the question.